# Install service to server 2012

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, windows-server-2012

I developed new service using .net 4.0 c#, I want now to install to hosting server which does not  contain visual studio command promot and installUtil.exe . How can Install the service to the server? It is required to install the VS version ?

Comment: Did you try `ServiceName.exe /install`?

Comment: Error message appeared. must install using installUtil

Comment: `InstallUtil.exe` is part of .NET Framework and can be located in `%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework[64]\<framework_version>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the solution :

1- copy **'InstallUtil.exe'** file to **c: dirve** in the server.

2- copy to the service execution file to same place.

3- open command promot in **'administrator mode'**(run as admin)

4- write the following command : **`c:\InstallUtil  c:\serviceName.exe`**

**Note : ensure that the service and Installer are both 32-bit or 64-bit**

Comment: You don't need to copy 'InstallUtil.exe'. It's already in the following directories:
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe

Answer (score 9):

1. Go to "C:\Windows\System32"
2. Right click on "cmd.exe" and "Run as administrator"
3. And run "InstallUtil.exe" like that:

   `"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe" "C:\src\Service.exe"`

   - The first parameter is the full path of InstallUtil.exe

     For 64 bit executables use following:

     > C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe

     For 32 bit executables use following:

     > C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe
   - The second parameter is the full path of Service.exe to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you a small refactor to implement the whole service using [Topshelf](http://topshelf-project.com/) and you'll be able to install your Windows services with no additional tool than the service executable itself.

For example, `yourexecutable install`, `yourexecutable uninstall`, `yourexecutable stop`, `yourexecutable start`...

Comment: Error message appeared. must install using installUtil

Comment: @RaedAlsaleh Have you checked the link? I'm suggesting you another way of implementing Windows services...

Comment: How can  I use install topshlef?